# Inserting to existing Excel file with OpemXML and C# is causing Excel problems with content and forcing repairs

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am able to run the following code without error or exception (on the code side)

```
private ExcelRow CreateContentRow(int index, StockHolder stockholder)
{
    ExcelRow r = new ExcelRow();
    r.RowIndex = (UInt32)index + 1;
    int i = 0;

    string[] headerColumns = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K" };
    var eraseThis = stockholder.GetType().GetProperties().Count();
    foreach (var prop in stockholder.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        ExcelCell c = new ExcelCell();
        c.CellReference = headerColumns[i].ToString() + index;

        if (prop.PropertyType.ToString().Equals("System.string", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var result = prop.GetValue(stockholder, null);

            if (result == null)
            {
                result = "";
            }

            c.DataType = CellValues.String;
            InlineString inlineString = new InlineString();
            Text t = new Text();
            t.Text = result.ToString();
            inlineString.AppendChild(t);
            c.AppendChild(inlineString);
        }

    //Other "if" statements here for checking bool and numeric (similar to the above "if" statement, but none of them are used at this time

    return r;
}
```

the "index" parameter is the number of rows  in the sheet I am attempting to add to (it seems able to read the sheet name (as there is only one anyway)), and the "Stockholder" parameter is the custom object with filled data (all are not null)

The issue is when i attempt to open the Excel document afterwards like this
[image: Excel Opening Error]

and when I click yes, it shows this popup
[image: Excel Opening Error Box]

results when I tried searching are more useful for another 3rd party library (starts with "ERPPS" or something like that). When debugging, the properties seem to map correctly (using another method for mapping, and they're all strings anyway). Any help or links would be appreciated as I've been working through this for a while now. and no, using a web app or a form is not an alternative at this time (shame as it would be over a long time ago). Thanks

EDIT -
Also, here is the calling method (since that may be part of it as well)

```
private void InsertIntoExistingExcel(StockHolder sh)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(locationOfExcelFile, true))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;
        var stockHolderInfo_Sheet = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.GetFirstChild<Sheet>();
        IEnumerable<Sheet> Sheets = new List<Sheet>() { stockHolderInfo_Sheet };
        if (Sheets.Count() > 0)
        {
            string relationshipId = Sheets.First().Id.Value;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            SheetData sheetdata = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            var sheetDataCount = sheetdata.Count();
            var newContentRow = CreateContentRow(sheetDataCount, sh);
            sheetdata.AppendChild(newContentRow);
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that _all_ the data you are adding is actually showing up in the workbook? I've gotten similar errors many times. There were a few different causes, but the most common was that the data I was adding was not in the document in the order Excel expected it. So Excel would ignore some of the data that was out of place. (I could see this happening with your appending the row at the end of the sheet.)

Comment: not sure.. I (shortly after posting this) went to another path. I've posted it as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

solved it! or rather, used a different method

```
    private void interopExcelInsertion(StockHolder sh, int rowNumberToUpdate)
    {
        ExcelInterop.Application oApp;
        ExcelInterop.Worksheet oSheet;
        ExcelInterop.Workbook oBook;

        oApp = new ExcelInterop.Application();
        oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Open(locationAndNameOfExcelFile);
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

        var rowToUpdate = rowNumberToUpdate > 0 ? rowNumberToUpdate : oSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(ExcelInterop.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, System.Type.Missing).Row;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var prop in sh.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var result = prop.GetValue(sh, null);
            oSheet.Cells[rowToUpdate + 1, i] = result == null ? "" : result.ToString();
            i++;
        }

        oBook.Save();
        oBook.Close();
        oApp.Quit();
        //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp);
    }
```